# Reg Ex Add a space character between alpha and numeric in a string

Tags: java, regex

Hi 
I have this kind of strings  and I want to obtain 
Like toto100 to become toto 100
Thanks for your help

Comment: Your programming language is...? And what about strings like: `100toto` and `1st`? Should they also be split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])
```

and replace that with a space. If you also want to split `100toto`, then use

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

This regex is looking for a position that is right after a letter and right before a digit. Since it doesn't have to match, conserve and replace any actual text, but rather just inserts a space in a position between two characters, this is quite fast.

As suggested by tchrist, of course it is better not to restrict yourself to ASCII letters and digits, especially if the language you're using supports Unicode in regular expressions (like Java does).

So the second regex looks like

```
(?<=\p{L])(?=\p{N})|(?<=\p{N})(?=\p{L})
```

In Java:

```
String result = subject.replaceAll("(?<=\\p{L])(?=\\p{N})|(?<=\\p{N})(?=\\p{L})", " ");
```

Comment: You *really* need to use `\pL` for letters.  Any time you see somebody write `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]` in a regular expression, it is virtually *always* wrong. `ˋunichars -a '\pL' '[^a-zA-Z]' | wc -lˋ` returns **12,917 code points that you’ve forgotten!**

Comment: @tchrist: Right. When the question was asked, there was no mention of Java, and I didn't rework the entire answer when this bit of information was added.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I pretty much assume that a regex language has Unicode support, because if it doesn’t, it really isn’t very useful anymore — wouldn’t you agree? Not only are characters no longer only 7 bites wide, they haven’t been such for a very long time. I really want people to move into the new millennium on this; it’s too important to keep ignoring.

Answer (score 1):

To borrow Tim’s solution but corrected to handle more than 1970’s ASCII — remember, Java characters are Unicode, so you have to account for that — gives this simple solution:

```
String new = old.replaceAll("(?x) (?<= \\pL ) (?= \\pN ) | (?<= \\pN ) (?= \\pL )", " ");
```

and this more-maintainable and less-insane version:

```
String new = old.replaceAll(
                "(?x)           # enable comment mode         \n"

              + " # LOOK FOR EITHER:                          \n"

              + "  (?<= \\pL )  #     a letter right behind   \n"
              + "  (?=  \\pN )  # AND a number right ahead    \n"

              + " |             #   OR ELSE                   \n"

              + "  (?<=  \\pN ) #     a number right behind   \n"
              + "  (?=   \\pL ) # AND a letter right ahead    \n"

              + "",             // placeholder so comma doesn't get lost

                " ");           // replaced with a single space
```

which I guess you could write like this so it’s not so far indented:

```
String new = old.replaceAll(
    "(?x)           # enable comment mode         \n"

  + "               # LOOK FOR EITHER:            \n"

  + "  (?<= \\pL )  #     a letter right behind   \n"
  + "  (?=  \\pN )  # AND a number right ahead    \n"

  + " |             #   OR ELSE                   \n"

  + "  (?<= \\pN )  #     a number right behind   \n"
  + "  (?=  \\pL )  # AND a letter right ahead    \n"

  + "",             // placeholder so comma doesn't get lost

  " ");             // replaced with a single space
```

That’s probably the best you’re going to be able to do, given how **horrendously ill-suited** Java is to this sort of work.   If you’ve only used Java, you probably aren’t even aware of how nasty it really is. Here in comparison is what the same operation looks like in a language that was actually *designed* with regexes in mind:

```
($new = $old) =~ s{  # LOOK FOR EITHER:
    (?<= \pL )       #      a letter right behind
    (?=  \pN )       #  AND a number right ahead
  |                  # OR ELSE:    
    (?<= \pN )       #      a number right behind
    (?=  \pL )       #  AND a letter right ahead
}{ }xg;              # THEN insert a single space
```

See all the many, *many* crucial differences?  Simply staggering, isn’t it?

I *can* do regex work in assembler if I want, too; in fact, I have. It’s just about as much fun as in Java, really.  Doing regex work in Java is too much like teaching a pig to sing: it’s a waste of your time and it annoys the pig; it also annoys everybody else, including you.

Learning to use the right tool for the right task is what separates the professional programmer from the code monkey. Life’s just too short to beat your head against a brick wall.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a language, here is one with Ruby:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "toto123".gsub(/([a-z]+)(\d+)/i, '\1 \2')
 => "toto 123"
```

But in other language, it is very similar.

Comment: @動靜能量: That is incorrect. You not only missed 12,917 letters (property `\pL`), you also missed 640 numbers (property `\pN`). Was that intentional?  How would **you** like it if somebody missed `"⁠動⁠靜⁠能⁠量⁠1987"`, eh? ☹

Comment: @tchrist the original question just asked for a regex without specifying a particular language

Comment: @動靜能量: Language actually doesn’t have much to do with it.  They asked for something “between an alpha and a numeric”.  There are several ways to specify that, including `\pL`, `\p{Letter}`, `\p{Cased_Letter}`, `\p{Alpha}` (*except* in Java, which is broken), `\p{Alphabetic}`, `\p{General_Category=Letter}`, `\pN`, `\p{Number}`, `\p{Nd}`, `\p{Decimal_Number}`, and `\p{Numeric_Type=Decimal}` — although those are not all synonyms. The question talked of alphas and numerics. The point here is that you **must not** attempt to enumerate a set of literal characters; you **must** use their properties.